# My profile is not showing correct information (towards the "Fanatic" badge)

Tags: discussion

I've been vigilantly visiting the site every day since january, and I've yet to receive the "Fanatic" badge. I can see that my profile says "visited 759 days, 9 consecutive", which is a surprise. 9 days ago would be May 11th, and according to my browser history I visited SO on May 9, 10, 11, 12 (and so on), all within the same UTC day.

Is the "consecutive" counting buggy, or have I miscalculated something?

Comment: You have to do slightly more than just load the site... To get an idea of what days have counted and the ones that haven't.... Go to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4353606/gthvidsten?tab=profile) and click on the "visited [...] consecutive" bit and you'll get a calendar you can scroll through... Days highlighted in green count as you having done enough to count as a "visit" for the fanatic badge.

Comment: @JonClements What is "slightly more"? Some days I've only loaded the site, and they count... so it doesn't seem like it's the same every time?

Comment: Don't think it's published what exactly counts... (and I don't know for sure)... However, it's probably performing some kind of action (asking/answering/commenting/voting) or looking at a few different posts (or making n many requests or something...) etc...