# Questions page in Meta not showing action taken

Tags: bug

This morning I was scrolling through the questions page of the Meta site and saw a question that didn't say what activity had taken place on it. As we all know it usually says modified/asked/answered x hours/mins ago by (user).

However I saw one that didn't specify its activity and was just empty. I checked the timeline of question and the activity that seems to match up is the fact it was migrated is it possible to show this on the main page?

Not that I think it is needed but here is a [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368265/my-profile-is-not-showing-correct-information-towards-the-fanatic-badge) to the question which is in the screenshot.

Browser IE 11.431.16299.0

[image]

Comment: It is a migration. My cross-site bug report on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304156/migrated-questions-dont-have-a-user-action-label-in-the-question-list

Comment: @rene ahh cross site dupes, they always catch everyone out, +1 for the freehand circle

Comment: Yeah, I try not to miss any opportunity to show off my red freehand circle skills ...